# Application error: resteasy-servlet did not complete its transaction

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, resteasy

```
2013-08-01 11:30:18,176 ERROR [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Application error: resteasy-servlet did not complete its transaction
```

The above is an error which I am getting in the server console. I am making a request with a certain client and if the client is `null` I am returning the response. I think this is because I am retuning the response without executing the full code.

**The following block is making this error**

```
   Users client = PersistanceService.findModel(Users.class, request.getClientId());
    //checking if its a valid client
    if (client == null) {
        LOGGER.warn("User not found : invalid client");
        return response;
    }
```

What should I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you build you response?

If not this should work:

```
return Response.status(theHTTPCOde).entity(yourBody/Message).build()
```

You could try something like this:

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("User not found : invalid client").build()
```